# How can I get the email to comment in any item as the app in Podio?

Tags: php, email, podio

Doing tests to get the email url and reviewing the documentation:
https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-area-22349 I get a response with data similar to this one:

"mailbox": The mailbox to use when mailing to the app,

It has the app id to sent mail…

- "url_label": "urlLabelResponse",
- "app_id": 11111111,
- "name": "appNameResponse",
- "item_name": "itemNameResponse",

…

- "status": "active",
- "default_view_id": null,
- "mailbox": "appname.2f2f2f2f",
- "is_default": false,

It has the hex value: 2f2f2f2f and reviewing the action , it uses a hex number within the mail itself.
This is the only “mailbox” mention so far and reviewing carefully the email, it looks like:

2.6d8248d7@appName.workspacename.organizationname.podio.com

so, the order is:

intNumber.HexNumber@appName.workspacename.organizationname.podio.com

I assumed the hex was the same within the app, and in my review, I realized the int number in the email, corresponds to the item id.

BUT… the hex number is different for EVERY SINGLE ITEM.

So, with (lets say, for example) the following data:

- App ID: 77665544

I get the mailbox:
"mailbox": "name.9f999999",
And different items looked like:

---

- Item ID: 735447534
- App ID: 77665544
- Workspace ID: 4444444
- Item e-mail: 3.1fd9a0b2@appName.workspacename.organizationname.podio.com

  ---
- Item ID: 731589225
- App ID: 77665544
- Workspace ID: 4444444
- Item e-mail: 2.f91aa7f4@appName.workspacename.organizationname.podio.com

  ---
- Item ID: 733288208
- App ID: 77665544
- Workspace ID: 4444444
- Item e-mail: 1.3bfa5531@ appName.workspacename.organizationname.podio.com

  ---

So, the biggest issue is to get the item email, or the hex in the email, is there any dev way to get it?

I tried in several ways without success, any help will be appreciated
Also in the review:
https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/articles/201290603-Email-to-item?mobile_site=true
https://blog.podio.com/2013/12/12/email-to-item/?_ga=2.57372202.1222208225.1510587163-1885911191.1491422608
https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200509658--Google-Apps-Add-e-mail-as-item-not-as-a-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't guess `email-to-app` email address or `email-to-item` email. That hex value that you've seen is generated randomly for each app and item. Luckily, you don't need to guess it at all because there is api call that will return that info.

Here are all details for api method you are looking for: 
https://developers.podio.com/doc/email/get-email-contact-for-reference-13716555

For email-to-item case: `name` would be `item_comment_user` and `ref_type` would be `item` and `ref_id` is `item_id`.

Comment: Thanks! You were really helpful, I wasn't understanding that particular part of the api!

Comment: If answer helps you, please accept and upvote it, so other users can benefit from the question/answer :)

Comment: Hi Pavlo!

Totally helpful! Was upvoted but this is a new account and I still don't have the reputation to be displayed.

Comment: That's weird, you should be able to accept answers for your questions.